# SPARQL query: How to have a new "null" element for each result

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

i'm making a project using .csv files that the DBpedia Sparql endpoint creates.
For the normal query there's no problem, i use this one for have the results:

```
    SELECT ?museum, ?artwork, ?abstract, ?thumbnail WHERE {
?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/address> ?address.
?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.
?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract.
?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?thumbnail.
 FILTER contains(?address, "Roma")
}
```

and it generates a table (museum - artwork - abstract .thumblink) ...

I would like to know if it's possible to have the same table with a element added like

table  (museum - artwork - abstract - thumblink - personal_element_code)

all the new element are good if they are null...

Thanks in advance

***UPDATE***

i've made a poit using this "kind" of query

```
SELECT ?museum ?artwork ?abstract ('null' as ?beacon_code) WHERE {

?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/address> ?address.
?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.
?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract.

 FILTER contains(?address, "Firenze")
}
```

note: do not flag:  "Strict checking of void variables"
It's kind barbaric but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your query isn't actually legal SPARQL.  There should not be commas between your projection variables.  DBpedia's endpoint, Virtuoso, is notorious for allowing some non-standard syntax.  It's particularly frustrating because if your *client* has to parse your query first, then something you try in the DBpedia webservice directly might not work with your client library.  You can check queries at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query).

In SPARQL, you can select variables that don't appear in your query, and they should have a sort of null value.  That is, you should simply be able to do:

```sql
SELECT ?museum ?artwork ?abstract ?thumbnail ?personal_element_code WHERE {
```

However, that doesn't actually work on the DBpedia endpoint (again, a Virtuoso oddity).  E.g., if you try the following query, you get the following error:

```sql
select ?person ?x where {
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person
}
limit 10
```

> Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable 'x' is used in the query result set but not assigned

However, you can work around this without too much trouble.  Just use **values ?x { undef }** in the body of the query.  E.g.:

```sql
select ?person ?x where {
  values ?x { undef }
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fperson%20%3Fx%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fx%20%7B%20undef%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If you request CSV for that, you'll get back the following, which has the empty column that you're looking for:

```
"person","x"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%81ngel_Gim%C3%A9nez",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aaron_Lines",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abel_Lafleur",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ada_Maimon",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Adam_Krikorian",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Constable",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(actress)",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(art_dealer)",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(fighter)",
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(footballer)",
```

If you actually just want the string null, this is all much easier.  You can just **('null' as ?x)**.  E.g.:

```sql
select ?person ('null' as ?x) where {
  values ?x { undef }
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fperson%20%28%27null%27%20as%20%3Fx%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fx%20%7B%20undef%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
"person","x"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%81ngel_Gim%C3%A9nez","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aaron_Lines","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abel_Lafleur","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ada_Maimon","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Adam_Krikorian","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Constable","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(actress)","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(art_dealer)","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(fighter)","null"
"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alex_Reid_(footballer)","null"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to treat data items that may be present, or may not, is to use OPTIONAL.

e.g.

```
SELECT ?museum ?artwork ?abstract ?thumbnail WHERE {
    ?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/address> ?address.
    ?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.
    FILTER contains(?address, "Roma")
    OPTIONAL{?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract.}
    OPTIONAL{?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?thumbnail.}
    }
```

Comment: I got the impression that OP isn't looking for an optional value, but for a way to introduce an empty column in to the result set so that the CSV has a "empty column" (presumably to match some processing that's expecting some number of columns).